# Trying to run a program in Pycharm

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm, python-idle

I have to test out a code in Pycharm (the bottom of the question), but I cannot figure out how to run it in Pycharm without getting this error:

```
usage: color.py [-h] -i IMAGE
color.py: error: the following arguments are required: -i/--image
```

I know that if I was using Idle I would have written this code:

```
/Users/syedrishad/Downloads/python-project-color-detection/color_detection.py -i 
Users/syedrishad/Downloads/python-project-color-detection/colorpic.jpg
```

But I don't know how to run it on Pycharm
I use a mac and for some reason i always have to put the full path name or it doesn't work.(If that makes a difference)
This program makes it so if I double click on a part of the image, it shows the exact color name. All the color names are stored in this file:

```
/Users/syedrishad/Downloads/python-project-color-detection/colors.csv
```

The actual code is here:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import argparse

#Creating argument parser to take image path from command line
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument('-i', '--image', required=True, help="Image Path")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
img_path = args['image']

#Reading the image with opencv
img = cv2.imread(img_path)

#declaring global variables (are used later on)
clicked = False
r = g = b = xpos = ypos = 0

#Reading csv file with pandas and giving names to each column
index=["color","color_name","hex","R","G","B"]
csv = pd.read_csv('colors.csv', names=index, header=None)

#function to calculate minimum distance from all colors and get the most matching color
def getColorName(R,G,B):
    minimum = 10000
    for i in range(len(csv)):
        d = abs(R- int(csv.loc[i,"R"])) + abs(G- int(csv.loc[i,"G"]))+ abs(B- int(csv.loc[i,"B"]))
        if(d<=minimum):
            minimum = d
            cname = csv.loc[i,"color_name"]
    return cname

#function to get x,y coordinates of mouse double click
def draw_function(event, x,y,flags,param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
        global b,g,r,xpos,ypos, clicked
        clicked = True
        xpos = x
        ypos = y
        b,g,r = img[y,x]
        b = int(b)
        g = int(g)
        r = int(r)
       
cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.setMouseCallback('image',draw_function)

while(1):

    cv2.imshow("image",img)
    if (clicked):
   
        #cv2.rectangle(image, startpoint, endpoint, color, thickness)-1 fills entire rectangle 
        cv2.rectangle(img,(20,20), (750,60), (b,g,r), -1)

        #Creating text string to display( Color name and RGB values )
        text = getColorName(r,g,b) + ' R='+ str(r) +  ' G='+ str(g) +  ' B='+ str(b)
        
        #cv2.putText(img,text,start,font(0-7),fontScale,color,thickness,lineType )
        cv2.putText(img, text,(50,50),2,0.8,(255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)

        #For very light colours we will display text in black colour
        if(r+g+b>=600):
            cv2.putText(img, text,(50,50),2,0.8,(0,0,0),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
            
        clicked=False

    #Break the loop when user hits 'esc' key    
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF ==27:
        break
    
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

If you know how to run, can you please tell me. I have been searching for an answer but come up empty-handed.

Comment: You can either hack the code to hard-code the command line arguments, or add them via `Run > Edit Configurations...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Yves Daoust mentioned you basically have two options:

A) Either change the code you are testing to provide the required argument or

B) Use *Run->Run...->Edit Configurations...* to provide the argument as you would from the command line.

Let's examine in more details the options you have:
A) The easiest way would be to provide the path to the image you want to open like this:

```
# replace img_path = args['image'] with
img_path = 'path/to/the/image'
```

which has the advantage of being extremely easy to get but it breaks the argparser functionality.

A more versatile solution would be to provide a default parameter and edit this one each time you want to open an image.

```
import argparse

# Add a global variable here. It will provide the argument if no other is given (via `Run->Run...->Edit Configurations...`)
IMAGE_PATH = 'path/to/image'
#Creating argument parser to take image path from command line
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument('-i', '--image', required=True, help="Image Path", default=IMAGE_PATH)
```

which has the advantage of keeping the arg parse functionality intact if you are interested in this one.

B) This option means you provide the parameters yourself just like you would do in the console. The parameters are put in the *Parameters:* field.
For example you could pass:

```
--image="path/to/image"
```

PyCharm provides the option to *Apply* (button) the changes you inserted (which in this case would mean to keep the parameters stored  for this script as long as the script will be in the memory).

Hope this clarify things a bit.

Comment: Hi thank you, its working without any direct errors but every time I run it a black thing pops up  instead of the actual image, then I get a message that python is not responding

Comment: Never mind, i just had forgotten to add back a part of the code

Comment: You can also upvote an answer if you find it useful (accepting it as the best answer typically means you found it useful). Of course you can upvote any answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to *Run > Run* and then select the program you want to run. If it still gives an error, check the file path, otherwise, you have an error in your code. I hope that answers your question.